# How to select only highlighted search results in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I have a folder with 5K images and want to select the items which match the search results, e.g.

[image]

With so many matches it would be time-consuming to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> each one. I'm sure there's a better way I just can't find one.
Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: On what basis would you choose the files? What are your criteria? You can search on extension AND date, for example. If you want to use RegExp, try a third-party tool, such as Agent Ransanck.

Comment: My criteria is any filename with ".jpg" in it. Not the extension, but in the title like the image shows. I need to delete those. How to isolate file names that contains this string?

Comment: Depends on what do you want to do with the selected images, for example, if you want to select all matching images to move them into another folder you can use a Powershell script like

```powershell
Get-ChildItem . | Where-Object {$_.Name -match ".*\.jpg.*"} | ForEach-Object {Move-Item -Path ".\$($_.Name)" "..\someFolder\"}  
```

Comment: Rather than make a *Comment*, edit our *Question*. Without that information, your question is unanswerable, but with that addition, the answer is below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find all files that have ".jpg" in the *filename* as well as in the extension, enter the following in Windows Search:

`filename:*jpg*.jpg`

Comment: Exactly what is needed, thank you!

Comment: For future visitors: and then `Ctrl`+`A` to select all in the list, once the list shows only what you need.